# Cycle with infinite length on $[0,1]$?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Suppose that every point in a unit interval $[0,1]$ is a node, and consider directed edges which can connect any point in unit interval to another.

I wonder if we can find any infinite cycle. I tried to find one using a convergent sequence $\{s_n\}$ converging toward $s^\infty$, where $s_n\rightarrow s_{n+1}$ and $s_\infty\rightarrow s_1$, but this can't be right because the sequence never reaches $s_\infty$.

Any idea on this? or examples?

Comment: What do you mean by an infinite cycle? The concept doesn't make sense until you define it.

Comment: I mean a cycle with infinite length. The reason I began to think about this questions is just I imagined every number in $[0,1]$ is connected to every other in $[0,1]$. In this case, I guess there's a cycle with an infinite length. But it is hard for me to imagine how it looks like. That's why I posted a question here. to know whether there's any other good example of this or not.

Comment: "Cycle" includes finite length in its definition.  You can have is an  path that extends infinitely in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if we can find any infinite cycle. I tried to find one using a convergent sequence $\{s_n\}$ converging toward $s^\infty$, where $s_n\rightarrow s_{n+1}$ and $s_\infty\rightarrow s_1$, but this can't be right because the sequence never reaches $s_\infty$.

And this holds true for any "cycle with infinite period". You'll never reach the link connecting back to the start to make a cycle. Either you accept the concept of [*infinite ordinals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) as a valid solution, or you do not. Based on that decision you either have many solutions, or you don't have any at all.

---

It is however possible to make directed edges such that you can find any cycle of arbitrary finite length. It's trivial in fact. Connect every number to $1$, and connect $x$ to $x/2$. Now starting at $1$ you can have an arbitrarily long cycle.

Comment: Could you explain little bit more about an example I take the concept of infinite ordinals as valid? I visited the link you made on your answer, but can't think of how it is connected to my answer..

Comment: Ordinals are a type of number where you can have infinities. The first infinity is written as $\omega$. If your convergent sequence starts at $1$, converges to $1/2$, and you then make the links $1/2 \to 1/4 \to 1$, then the cycle length would be $\omega + 2$. If you make a convergent sequence starting at $1$ converging to $1/2$, and then another one from $1/2$ to $1/4$ (each convergent sequence taking an infinite number of steps, mind you), and so on, and finally link $0$ to $1$ , you would have a cycle length of $\omega \cdot \omega + 1= \omega^2 + 1$. That's an example of infinite ordinals.